# How to host in 5gbfree?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting

I have a domain registered with godaddy and a free hosting in 5gbfree, installed wordpress in this and I don't know how to map my domain to this hosting. can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

According to the knowledge-base article [here](https://www.5gbfree.com/faq/what-are-the-nameservers-for-domain-registration/) , 5GBFree has following default nameservers.

NS1.5GBFree.com

NS2.5GBFree.com

Just login to Godaddy domain control panel and set above nameservers. Here's the tutorial you should follow.

https://www.godaddy.com/help/set-custom-nameservers-for-domains-registered-with-us-12317

Comment: thanks for your reply. 

I tried to resolve the issue and now I can access the admin area

ie, for eg : www. xyz .com/wp-admin,

But I am not getting the public side 

ie, www. xyz .com

Comment: It's a typical wordpress problem and you would find plenty of fixes to resolve it..Here's one of them.. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/site-white-screen-can-access-wp-admin ...You can also ask your web host or google it your self.